# error changing root controller from navigation to tab

Tags: ios5

I have a project that starts off with a navigation controller that goes to table view controller.
I'm now trying to make a tab controller first, but i'm getting the following error. The error doesn't occur if the tab controller isn't there.

2012-06-26 18:12:31.639 Medicine Tracker[1212:fb03] -[UITabBarController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d64970
2012-06-26 18:12:31.667 Medicine Tracker[1212:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d64970'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16b4022 0x1845cd6 0x16b5cbd 0x161aed0 0x161acb2 0x3dc7 0x1d386 0x1e274 0x2d183 0x2dc38 0x21634 0x159eef5 0x1688195 0x15ecff2 0x15eb8da 0x15ead84 0x15eac9b 0x1dc65 0x1f626 0x278d 0x26f5)
terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **topViewController** method is not a member of UITabBarController. It does have a method called **selectedViewController**, which might provide the functionality that you need.

[UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: seems its this thats causing it

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    mt_MasterViewController *controller = (mt_MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}